# Exception when trying to SaveChanges with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, checkbox, mvvm

I am building an MVVM WPF app in Visual Studio 2015 using Entity Framework 6. The app has a view with a few checkbox:

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="0"
           Grid.Column="0"
           Style="{StaticResource FieldLabel}"
           Text="Inactive" />
<CheckBox Grid.Row="0"
          Grid.Column="1"
          IsChecked="{Binding IsSelectedEmployeeInActive,
                              Mode=TwoWay}" />
<TextBlock Grid.Row="1"
           Grid.Column="0"
           Style="{StaticResource FieldLabel}"
           Text="Leave of Absence" />
<CheckBox Grid.Row="1"
          Grid.Column="1"
          IsChecked="{Binding IsSelectedEmployeeLoa,
                              Mode=TwoWay}" />
<TextBlock Grid.Row="2"
           Grid.Column="0"
           Style="{StaticResource FieldLabel}"
           Text="Archived" />
<CheckBox Grid.Row="2"
          Grid.Column="1"
          IsChecked="{Binding IsSelectedEmployeeArchived,
                              Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Each of these checkboxes is bound to a property, such as the following:

```
public bool IsSelectedEmployeeInActive
{
    get { return _isSelectedEmployeeInActive; }
    set
    {
        if (_isSelectedEmployeeInActive == value) return;

        _isSelectedEmployeeInActive = value;

        if (value)
        {
            var count = SelectedEmployee.EmployeeStatus.Count(x => x.validEmployeeStatusID.Equals(2));
            if (count.Equals(0))
            {
                SelectedEmployee.EmployeeStatus.Add(new EmployeeStatu
                {
                    employeeID = SelectedEmployee.employeeID,
                    validEmployeeStatusID = 2,
                    exitDate = DateTime.Now,
                    createdDate = DateTime.Now
                });
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var itemToRemove = SelectedEmployee.EmployeeStatus.Single(x => x.validEmployeeStatusID.Equals(2));
            Context.Entry(itemToRemove).State = EntityState.Deleted;
            SelectedEmployee.EmployeeStatus.Remove(itemToRemove);
        }
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => IsSelectedEmployeeInActive);
    }
}
```

The `SelectedEmployee` property gets set when the user clicks a row on a DataGrid. In the view model's constructor, the app has an event handler for changes to `SelectedEmployee`:

```
this.PropertyChanged += (o, e) =>
{
    if (e.PropertyName == nameof(this.SelectedEmployee))
    {
        IsSelectedEmployeeLoa = (SelectedEmployee.EmployeeStatus
                .Count(x => x.validEmployeeStatusID.Equals(2)) > 0);
        IsSelectedEmployeeArchived = (SelectedEmployee.EmployeeStatus
                .Count(x => x.validEmployeeStatusID.Equals(5)) > 0);
        IsSelectedEmployeeInActive = (SelectedEmployee.EmployeeStatus
                .Count(x => x.validEmployeeStatusID.Equals(4)) > 0);
    }
};
```

When the user clicks the Save button, it calls the following via a RelayCommand:

```
public void SaveEmployees()
{
    Context.SaveChanges();
}
```

If I change the CheckBox controls a few times between checked and unchecked and click Save, the app blows up with this exception on the `Context.SaveChanges()` line above:

> {"Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=472540 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions."}

If I comment out the code in the event handler for `SelectedEmployee` that sets the checkbox properties, the error goes away; but then I'm not able to set the CheckBox properties to their initial values from the database.

How should I resolve this issue? Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you use a "Default" button to retreive data from database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I bet it is because you are adding a new EmployeeStatus when the checkbox is checked:

```
            SelectedEmployee.EmployeeStatus.Add(new EmployeeStatu
            {
                employeeID = SelectedEmployee.employeeID,
                validEmployeeStatusID = 2,
                exitDate = DateTime.Now,
                createdDate = DateTime.Now
            });
```

and then later when you uncheck the checkbox, setting its state to deleted:

```
        var itemToRemove = SelectedEmployee.EmployeeStatus.Single(x => x.validEmployeeStatusID.Equals(2));
        Context.Entry(itemToRemove).State = EntityState.Deleted;
        SelectedEmployee.EmployeeStatus.Remove(itemToRemove);
```

The database can't delete it when you call save because it was never actually added to the database... it was only added to the context. You will need to check if it is a newly added record or not. Try something like this, I usually like to test code before I post it but I don't have time right now...

```
if (Context.Entry(itemToRemove).State != EntityState.Added)
   Context.Entry(itemToRemove).State = EntityState.Deleted;
else
   Context.Entry(itemToRemove).State = EntityState.Detached;
```

Comment: Thanks, @J.H. I was not saving the changes and the entities were getting into an inconsistent state -- doing adds and deletes on top of each other. This fixed the problem!